# PHP Select single checkbox value from database and assign to a variable

Tags: php, checkbox

I have in my table from database 3 rows of tinyint type which are called: `option1`,`option2`,`option3`. I want to assing them value to variables `$int1`,`$int2`,`$int3`. + I have in my script 3 checkboxes and I want to check if checkboxes value is equal with checkboxes value from database. For example: if checkbox1 is checked && checkbox2 is checked, in above if, if checkbox1 value == $int1 && checkbox2 value == $int2, I don't know how to make this in my script, can anybody help me? I don't put the script here because I don't have any checkbox in it.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you want to do? As there's no script for me to work from. This is what I got from your description.

```
if($_POST&&isset($_POST['submit'])/*submit button*/){
    $DBH=new mysqli('location','user','pass','database');
    $get=$DBH->prepare('SELECT option1,option2,option3 FROM table');
    $get->execute();
    $get->bind_result($int1,$int2,$int3);//bearing in mind that I think you have one record in this table? 
    $get->close();
    if($int1==int$_POST['checkbox1']&&$int2==int$_POST['checkbox2']&&$int3==int$_POST['checkbox3'])echo'All match';
    else echo'Something didn\'t match.';
}
```

There's ultimately 1000's of ways of doing what you want to do. I'm not sure what you want to do so I've guessed :p Hope it gives you some insight into what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This line is ok: `if($int1==int$_POST['checkbox1']&&$int2==int$_POST['checkbox2']&&$int3==int$_POST['checkbox3'])echo'All match';
    else echo'Something didn\'t match.';`, but I don't understand that bind_result, because my main query is: `SELECT * FROM questions order by rand() LIMIT 1`. With bind_result I assing to `$int1` the `option1` value from database?

Comment: Well I don't know!! You didn't give me any code to work from!

Answer (score 0):

`<?php 
    $DBH=new mysqli('location','user','pass','database');
    $get=$DBH->prepare('SELECT option1,option2,option3 FROM table');
    $get->execute();
    $get->bind_result($int1,$int2,$int3);
    $get->close();
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="int1" value ="value1" <?php echo ($int1=="value1")?"checked:'checked'":"";?>/>
<input type="checkbox" name="int2" value ="value2" <?php echo ($int1=="value1")?"checked:'checked'":"";?>/>
<input type="checkbox" name="int3" value ="value3" <?php echo ($int3=="value3")?"checked:'checked'":"";?>/>`

Hope this helps